# Некорректный вывод значений поля структуры

Tags: golang

Доброго времени суток.

Написал парсер, который собирает со страницы данные и присваивает значения полям структуры.
При таком выводе :

```
fmt.Println(someStruct)
```

некоторые строковые поля структуры выводятся в таком виде: \320\221\320\276\320\263\320\270\320\275\321\201\320\272\320\270\320\271 \320\220\320\275\320\264\321\200\320\265\320\271 \320\230\320\262\320\260\320\275\320\276\320\262\320\270\321\207

если же выводить их вот так :

```
fmt.Println(someStruct.Name)
```

вывод корректен.

Примерно понимаю, что дело в кириллице и кодировке, но ответа в в инете не нашел(

P.S. На сайте, с которого собираю данные, кодировка UTF-8
Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: а если так `fmt.Printf("%+v\n", someStruct)` ?

Comment: Что написано у вас в `SomeStruct.ToString`?  Там явно что-то просисходит с перекодированием в байты.